# Find all users and update them at once

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

is there a way to find all users and update them at the same time?

This code works with findOneAndUpdate or findByIdAndUpdate, but only remove the record from one user.

I need to remove the objects inside "topicsfollowed" that match the (req.params.id) from all users at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

```
User.find({}, { $pull: {topicsfollowed: req.params.id}}, function (err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('index.ejs', { errors:errors });
      }
      res.send('Success')
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

> 1) {multi:true} to update Multiple documents in mongoose .
>
> 2) use update query to update Multiple documents ,If you are using
>   findOneAndUpdate query only one record will be updated.

```
 User.update({},{$pull: {topicsfollowed:req.params.id}},{multi: true}, function(err, result) {

})
```

Comment: Incredible. I had the {multi: true} before but was getting an error (not related with {multi: true}) and a removed it. Thanks a lot. This delete the recored from the users